# Error! Not more than one entry file/directory is expected

Tags: error-handling, command-line-interface

I'm trying to build a cli tool with the following command

```
npx pkg . -d --targets node14-macos-x64 -- output bin/macos/metaplex
```

Which gives me the error in the title.

```
Error! Not more than one entry file/directory is expected
```

Any idea why I'm getting this error and unable to build the cli tool in the output folder specified?

Thanks for the help. :)